# Client-side image resizing with cubic interpolation?

Tags: html, image, image-processing, upload

I'm wanting to have a web interface for batch-uploading and resizing images to my server. I've seen quite a few solutions for resizing images client-side, most of them flash based. I really don't care what technology a client-side image resizer uses as long as it:

1. Is reasonably fast
2. Resizes images with some sort of interpolation (cubic will do just fine)

Does anyone know of something that would be good for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Hey, try this tutorial: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET

It uses a jQuery plugin called JCrop.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, but that seems only to be for cropping images. I'm looking for some sort of client-side bicubic resizing.